# Create a strong typed wrapper around Asp.Net Core Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I searched for wrapper for claims and I have found nothing so i assume this is impossible to implement or just so easy that i'm missing something.

I want to try implement something I can use to access or add new claims but i don't know where to start.

For example...

```
 HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Referencia").Value
```

Where can i write a class to wrap around claims and tell my app to use this class?

I just would like to do something like this

```
_claimsWrapper.GetClaim();
```

Comment: Point is to have strong typed claims for custom claims i might add during login and write less code, as you can see on the long string on my post, plus would be nice to see which type is returned, sometimes i forget if it's the int or string

Comment: That is the intended, except i would like to know how can i inject on my pagemodels this wrapper class and access the claims from it

Comment: Extension methods on the ClaimsPrincipal could work also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Point is to have strong typed claims for custom claims i might add during login and write less code, as you can see on the long string on my post, plus would be nice to see which type is returned, sometimes i forget if it's the int or string

You could make C# extension class, e.g.

```
public static class ClaimsIdentitExtensions
{
    public static string GetReferencia(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        return user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Referencia")?.Value;
    }

}
```

In your controller you could do:

```
User.GetReferencia();
```

In the view you could use:

```
@User.GetReferencia()
```

If you need this is a Model, you could pass the User to the model (e.g. contructor)

Comment: Elegant and simple. Love It.
Can even shortened:
`return user.FindFirstValue("Referencia");`